# Como usar "background-image" corretamente?

Tags: image, background-image

Este comando abaixo é o que eu uso no MENU atual do meu Blog, porém eu gostaria de mudar o visual e colocar uma imagem de fundo no MENU. como faço isso usando o "background-image"? onde salvo a imagem para ser buscada pelo comando? como saber o diretório da imagem?

```
#PageList1 ul {
border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
```

Answer (score 0):

sai um nível e entra na pasta img

```
PageList1 ul {
   border-top: 2px solid #ccc; 
   border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc; 
   background-image: url("../img/remove-icon-small.png") !important;
}
```

mesmo nível do arquivo css e entra na pasta img

```
PageList1 ul {
   border-top: 2px solid #ccc; 
   border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc; 
   background-image: url("/img/remove-icon-small.png") !important;
}
```

mesma nível do css sem entrar em nenhuma pasta

```
PageList1 ul {
   border-top: 2px solid #ccc; 
   border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc; 
   background-image: url("remove-icon-small.png") !important;
}
```

Você deve considerar a url da imagem de acordo com a estrutura de pastas
se a imagem esta na mesma raiz do arquivo css então desconsidere colocar `../` assim por diante.

Comment: Desculpe mas continuo não entendendo onde salvar a imagem e encontrar seu diretório, digamos que eu queira usar essa imagem do link como background: https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/21/13/28/banner-1406825_960_720.png ...como pode ver ela esta online. o que devo fazer? salvar onde? ou posso usar a URL? é realmente possível usar ela como fundo do MENU?

Comment: Salve a imagem localmente. voce nao entendeu os 3 exemplos que escrevi, percebeu a diferença entre os niveis de pasta em relação ao seu arquivo css?

Comment: desculpe, sou iniciante em CSS, tenho apenas uma noção de como funciona mas não conheço a estrutura completa... queria apenas conseguir usar "baground-image",   faria muita diferença pra mim hoje.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela atençao amigo... já consegui resolver, hospedando a imagem aqui: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/upl.php, e copiando a URL da mesma.